# Can you advice to use Metro UI CSS on Web Projects?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am not at good on web design.So generally I use bootstrap framework on my web projects.But I looked into  metro css ui https://metroui.org.ua/ . It seems look good. But I confused I I use or not.

Can you advice it to use on web projects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) First Download the Metro CSS,

2) Add Metro.css and metro.js in your header.

3) Change / use classes and ids as per you need.

Above are the basic steps to use any theme / HTML in web Project

Comment: I know how to do it.I am not asking to this.